# how to extract a particular string

Tags: excel, excel-2010, extract

i want to extract `"eirnan"` plus the other numeric followed by it.
i cant find any matching solution for this..

example

```
Please indicate/  the correct salesman id (Should be _Eirnan413431 _)
Please indicateEirnan3659 /  the correct salesman id (Should be __)
Please indicate / Eirnan84215; the correct salesman id (Should be __)
Eirnan421/Please indicate /  the correct salesman id (Should be __)
Please indicate/  the correct salesman id Eirnan4752151 /(Should be __)
```

please help

im using EXCEL 2010

Comment: can you explain with cell value as exampple

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this formula in B1 and copy down?

```
=MID(A1,FIND("Eirnan",A1,1),MAX(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),0))-FIND("Eirnan",A1,1)+1)
```

[image]

`Right click` on image and `open in new tab` to see it in full size.

Based on code from MVP Ron Coderre on [MrExcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/367606-last-numeric-character-position-string.html).